# Sort images from newest to oldest PHP

Tags: php, image, sorting, directory

Hi I have the following script to show images from a directory and make thumbs , but I would like to know how to sort the images from newest to oldest and how to implement it in this script
Many Thanks in Advance!

```
<?php
    # SETTINGS
    $max_width = 800;
    $max_height = 600;
    $per_page = 10;

    $page = $_GET['page'];

    $has_previous = false;
    $has_next = false;

$images = array();
$times = array();
// read the images folder for jpg, jpeg, png and gif images using glob() - see http://php.net/glob for info
foreach(glob('images/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $image)
{
    // add the file to the images array
    $images[] = $image;

    // get the files creation/last modification timestamp add it to the times array. 
    // This array will be used later to sort the images array
    $times[] = filemtime($image);

   // generate the image thumbnail if needed
   if(!file_exists('thumbs/' . $image))
   {
       // calling your makeThumb function, pass it the file extension for the image
       makeThumb(basename($image), pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
   }
}
// using the times array, to sort the images newest to oldest
array_multisort($times , SORT_DESC, 
                $images);



    function getPictures() {
        global $page, $per_page, $has_previous, $has_next;
        if ( $handle = opendir(".") ) {
            $lightbox = rand();
            echo '<ul id="pictures">';

            $count = 0;
            $skip = $page * $per_page;

            if ( $skip != 0 )
                $has_previous = true;

            while ( $count < $skip && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
                if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' )
                    $count++;
            }
            $count = 0;
            while ( $count < $per_page && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
    if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' ) {

        // make the thumbs directory if it doesn't already exist
        if ( ! is_dir('thumbs') ) {
            mkdir('thumbs');
        }
        // make a thumbnail if it doesn't already exist
        if ( ! file_exists('thumbs/'.$file) ) {
            makeThumb( $file, $type );
        }

        // create a link to $file, add the thumbnail
        echo '<li><a href="' . $file . '">';
        echo '<img src="thumbs/'.$file.'" alt="" /></a></li>';
        $count++;

echo substr($file,strlen($folder),strpos($file, '.')-strlen($folder));

    }
}

            echo '</ul>';

            while ( ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
                if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' ) {
                    $has_next = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function getPictureType($file) {
        $split = explode('.', $file); 
        $ext = $split[count($split) - 1];
        if ( preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i', $ext) ) {
            return 'jpg';
        } else if ( preg_match('/png/i', $ext) ) {
            return 'png';
        } else if ( preg_match('/gif/i', $ext) ) {
            return 'gif';
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    function makeThumb( $file, $type ) {
        global $max_width, $max_height;
        if ( $type == 'jpg' ) {
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
        } else if ( $type == 'png' ) {
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
        } else if ( $type == 'gif' ) {
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
        }
        if ( ($oldW = imagesx($src)) < ($oldH = imagesy($src)) ) {
            $newW = $oldW * ($max_width / $oldH);
            $newH = $max_height;
        } else {
            $newW = $max_width;
            $newH = $oldH * ($max_height / $oldW);
        }
        $new = imagecreatetruecolor($newW, $newH);
        imagecopyresampled($new, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newW, $newH, $oldW, $oldH);
        if ( $type == 'jpg' ) {
            imagejpeg($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
        } else if ( $type == 'png' ) {
            imagepng($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
        } else if ( $type == 'gif' ) {
            imagegif($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
        }
        imagedestroy($new);
        imagedestroy($src);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UFT-8" />
<title>Pictures</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    width:780px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#pictures li {
    float:left;
    height:<?php echo ($max_height + 10); ?>px;
    list-style:none outside;
    width:<?php echo ($max_width + 10); ?>px;
    text-align:center;
}
img {
    border:0;
    outline:none;
}
.prev {
    float:left;
}
.next {
    float:right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php getPictures(); ?>

<div style="clear:both"></div>

<?php
    if ( $has_previous )
        echo '<p class="prev"><a href="?page='.($page - 1).'">&larr; Previous Page</a></p>';

    if ( $has_next )
        echo '<p class="next"><a href="?page='.($page + 1).'">Next Page &rarr;</a></p>';
?>

<div style="clear:both"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Comment: what did you tried ? Have a look to PHP `sort` and `usort` functions (http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php and http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: I'm not sure where to start, im a rookie at this...

Comment: So no try at all? did you copied the above code?

Comment: First of all, you have to separate your data (the picture list) from your view (the way it appears). Step 1: get all the data needed and store it into an array. Use `filemtime` to also retrieve the file modification time as pointed by @Hanky웃Panky. Step 2: use PHP sort functions to sort this array as you wish. Step 3: display this new array the way you want.

Comment: Have a look at the sort functions @pomeh provided - if you play around with them their purpose will become clear. Yes, read this information into an array first. Please do give it a try!

Comment: I had a look at the example on [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371042/sort-pictures-by-date-newest-first-in-php) but seems like it needs modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filemtime($file);` for getting the last modification date of your file. You can store your files in an array and use the timestamps as keys. You can sort the array contents by the keys with php easily and just foreach through the sorted array and output it like that. Another advice: You should store your file paths, extensions, upload/modification dates and file sizes in database, it would save much work for you. I hope my answer was helpful.
The code:

```
<?php
function sort_images($basedir){
  $dir = scandir($basedir);
  $files = array();
  foreach($dir as $filename){
    $mimetype = mime_content_type($filename);
    if(explode('/', $mimetype)[0] == 'image'){
      $mod_time = filemtime(basedir.'/'.$filename;
      $files[$mod_time] = $basedir.'/'.$filename;
    }
  }

  $sorted = ksort($files);
  return $sorted;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1   /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UFT-8" />
<title>Pictures</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php foreach(sort_images('foo/bar') as $image): ?>
<div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so if I understand correct I should add the php part to the script and remove my current `<?php getPictures(); ?>` and replace it with your `<?php foreach(sort_images('foo/bar') as $image): ?>
<div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>` am I correct?

Comment: It does not creates pagination, you can modify my code if you wish. This code outputs every single image on 1 page, it just shows you a way of sorting the images by modification time. I rather suggest you reuse this code and implement the method into your own script. Do not copy the whole code(bad practice) just use the stuff you need from it. Note that filemtime returns a unix timestamp, you can convert it to date format with date($format, $timestamp) function.

Comment: Note: mime_content_type($filename) will only work with php 5.3 and above. If you run an older version you should use the finfo functions. Example: $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename).'<br/>';